# La BD me devuelve el boolean como nulo

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

Tengo una clase cuenta y tiene un boolean. Yo creo sin problemas el DTO y la entidad pero a la hora de listar el boolean me lo devuleve como nulo.
Siento que este en ingles el codigo pero el que me lo ha pedido lo quiere asi.

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "Accounts")
public class Account implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "currency")
    private Currency currency;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "balance")
    private BigDecimal balance;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "treasury")
    private boolean treasury;

    public Account(String name, Currency currency, BigDecimal balance, boolean treasury) {
        this.name = name;
        this.currency = currency;
        this.balance = balance;
        this.treasury = treasury;
    }

    public Account() {
        treasury = false;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Currency getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    public void setCurrency(Currency currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    public BigDecimal getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(BigDecimal balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public boolean getTreasury() {
        return treasury;
    }
}
```

este es el metodo que no creo que influya pero bueno

```
@GetMapping
@ResponseBody
public List<AccountDTO> findAll() {
    List<Account> listaMedicos = aS.findAll();
    return listaMedicos.stream().map(transformers::transformerToDTO).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

}

esta es la salida de consolta

```
    Hibernate: select account0_.name as name1_0_, account0_.balance as balance2_0_, account0_.currency as currency3_0_, account0_.treasury as treasury4_0_ from accounts account0_
2021-01-12 23:17:57.691 TRACE 9760 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([name1_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [Cuenta]
2021-01-12 23:17:57.692 TRACE 9760 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([balance2_0_] : [NUMERIC]) - [1200.00]
2021-01-12 23:17:57.692 TRACE 9760 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([currency3_0_] : [VARCHAR]) - [EUR]
2021-01-12 23:17:57.692 TRACE 9760 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor   : extracted value ([treasury4_0_] : [BOOLEAN]) - [false]
```

esta del postman

```
  [
    {
        "name": "Cuenta",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "balance": 1200.00,
        "treasury": null
    }
]
```

Comment: Esto es java? que tiene que ver mysql aca?

Comment: porque conecta con mysql no se si importa o no los datos los saca de una BD mysql

Comment: Hola, por favor agrega el metodo `transformerToDTO`. El problema puede estar ahi

Comment: Agrega el setter correspondiente al campo `treasury`